# How to unwrap a mesh generated with "screw"?

Tags: uv, modifiers, screw-modifier

I made a quad, then deleted all edges except one.
Then I added a Screw Modifier on that, this is the result so far:

[image]

Now how would I unwrap this? I don't want to lose the ability to change settings, so I don't want to click Apply on the modifier.

And when I press U the unwrap option is not available.

What are my options?

Comment: using object texture coordinates? Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the first question, sorry :( But the setting at the top is set to BlenderRender. Does that make any difference when exporting for Unity?

Comment: OK. I think that if it is to export to unity, at one moment, the UV map have to be defined. So even if you can texture it before having the UV map (and you can't have it in this situation as you have no faces), you cannot obtain the same rendering in anyway (IMO) after that with a UV generated just before the export.