# How to add faces to object made with screw modifier?

Tags: uv

I just started learning Blender and I made a simple chess pawn using screw modifier (followed Grant Abbitt tutorial). Now I want to make UV map to use it in Unity with wood material but it doesn't have faces atm.

How do I add/generate faces for this object?

[image: Pawn I made]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74428/how-to-unwrap-a-mesh-generated-with-screw

Comment: You need to apply the modifier?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the modifier if you want the UVs:

[image]